Why the following system is not a basis in $l_p$?
Let $e_i(n) = \delta_{i,n}$ for $i \in N$. Why this system is not a basic in $(l_p, ||x||_p)$ (where $||x||^p_p = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} |x_i|^p$) for $1 \le p \lt +\infty$?
Lets fix $x \in l_p$. For any $\epsilon \gt 0$ I can take such $N$ that $\sum_{i=N+1}^{+\infty} |x_i|^p \lt \epsilon$, so $||x - \sum_{i=1}^{N} e_i x(i)||^p_p \lt \epsilon$. So, because coefficients in this series are fixed (not changed with different $\epsilon$), it is a basis. Where am I wrong?
I saw a strange proof that $l_p$ does not have countable basis here (pt. 2): Normed vector space & Schauder basis exercise but I don't agree with it (why such functions are in $l_p$)? Unfortunately, I can't leave a comment under that question.

You are mixing up different notions of basis. Finite linear combinations of $(e_i)$ do not exhaust $\ell_p$ and this is what is meant by saying that $(e_i)$ is not a (Hamel) basis.

Hmm, sounds like you are right. I should be more attentive next time. Thank you!
